# using Polybase and Stored procedure for updating dbo.table from several external tables

Tags: sql, azure, blob, polybase

I need some help in this..
I have 3 external tables:

```
create external table ext.titanic
(
PassengerId INT,
Pclass INT,
Pname VARCHAR(100),
Gender VARCHAR(20),
Ticket VARCHAR(30),
Cabin VARCHAR(30)
)
WITH (LOCATION='/titanic.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = blob1,  
    FILE_FORMAT = TextFileFormat1,
);

create external table ext.titanic2
(
Pclass INT,
Pname VARCHAR(100)
)
WITH (LOCATION='/titanic2.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = blob1,  
    FILE_FORMAT = TextFileFormat1,
);

create external table ext.titanic3
(
PassengerId INT,
Pname VARCHAR(100),
)
WITH (LOCATION='/titanic3.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = blob1,  
    FILE_FORMAT = TextFileFormat1,
);
```

and i have dbo table created:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.titanic
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
)
AS

SELECT 

titanic.PassengerId,
titanic.Pclass,
titanic.Pname,
titanic.Gender,
titanic.Ticket,
titanic.Cabin,
titanic3.PassengerId as T3_PassengerId,
titanic3.Pname as T3_Pname,
titanic2.Pclass as T2_Pclass,
titanic2.Pname as T2_Pname

FROM ext.titanic
FULL JOIN ext.titanic2 ON ext.titanic2.PassengerId=ext.titanic.PassengerId
FULL JOIN ext.titanic3 ON ext.titanic3.Pclass=ext.titanic.Pclass;
```

I have to join them and update the dbo.titanic with a stored procedure

do i need additional ext.table to join them there and after that to merge it with dbo.titanic?

or there is a easy and simple way to do that?

also i need more help for the dbo.titanic and joins..

there are more unique PassengerIds in titanic3 than in titanic,
but i need all PassengerIds from the 2 tables to be in one column..  same for Pclass from both tables... that is bugging me

just for reference - titanic table has around 100000 rows(800 unique PassengerIDs) and titanic2 and titanic3 have 5000 unique (total)rows for PassengerId and Pclass.

The final table must look like dbo.titanic but without T3_PassengerId and T2_Pclass as they must be merged somehow in the PassengerId and Pclass.

I lost a lot of time looking for something like that, but didn't find anything close enough.

This is the best I could find:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/access-external-data-from-azure-synapse-analytics-using-polybase

and I want to thank the guy that wrote this,
but to use it, I have 3 main issues :

1. there are no 3 external tables with different columns that need to be joined
2. there is no update so this can be used after the creation of the tables.(as I understand update cant be used with external tables)
3. there is no stored procedure used for this update.

Can I use something like this

`INSERT INTO table1(column1, column2,...) SELECT  column1, column2,... FROM  table2 WHERE  condition( compare value in table1 <> value in table 2)`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this...

may be not the most elegant way but it works.. using **left join**, with additional stg.titanic table (same as dbo.titanic) that combines the 3 external tables.. then merge stg. and dbo. tables..

```
MERGE dbo.titanic AS [Target]
USING (SELECT 
 column1,2,3
  UpdateTime
 from stg.titanic) AS [Source] 
 ON [Target].PassengerId = [Source].PassengerId 
 and [Target].Pclass = [Source].Pclass 
 and [Target].Pname = [Source].Pname --- specifies the condition
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET [Target].UpdateTime = GetDate()  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (column1,2,3 --- when one of the 3 conditions is not met then insert new row
 UpdateTime)
VALUES (
  [Source].column1,2,3
  [Source].UpdateTime
);
```

if someone knows a better way it will be good to share with us

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must not create another ext.table; the way Polybase works is that it will load all data to Temp tables and then it can be merged to dbo.titanic.
2. Perform a left/right join if the tables don't have the same IDs but you need all of them.
3. Use the following code, then it will be easy to create the SP:
   ;WITH [MyCTE] AS (SELECT ...) UPDATE dbo.titanic SET ...;
4. You can't update using Polybase, you will have to create a new file i.e. titanic4.csv which has the records joined.

Please try and update with your progress, so I can help you further.

Comment: can I use : INSERT INTO table1(column1, column2,...) SELECT  column1, column2,... FROM  table2 WHERE  condition( compare value in table1 <> value in table 2) here it wont let me compare...    or can you write a little bit more of this example with CTE because i don't get it. thanks

Comment: I want to add new rows to dbo.titanic every time i get new CSV and if values in 2 fields are different - titanic.PassengerId OR titanic.Ticket ...

Comment: You can't include this logic, you can delete the .csv after imported, then the procedure remains the same. Forget about the CTE, you can use: INSERT INTO titanic(column1, column2, ...) SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM table2 LEFT JOIN titanic ON titanic.PassengerId = table2.PassengerId WHERE titanic.PassengerId IS NULL.